# Is "stife" a name for smoking cooking oil?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, is-it-a-word

My parents and grandparents used to describe smoking cooking oil as "stife". Has anyone else heard of this? Perhaps I've spelt it wrong?

Comment: Where are your parents and grandparents from?

Answer (score 19):

[Dictionaries of the Scots Language](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/stife) defines *stife* ("Also st(e)yfe; stoif") as:

> A close, suffocating atmosphere, a choking vapour or smoke, a smoky sulphurous smell (Dmf. s.Sc. 1825 Jam.; Rxb. 1923 Watson W.-B.; s.Sc. 1971). Also in n.Eng. dial.

This would seem to apply to smoking cooking oil.

In other words, something that **stifles**; the word is apparently a back formation thereof. [OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/stife_n?tab=factsheet#20678924) attests it as far back as 1636.

Answer (score 14):

*Stife* (also *styfe*) is a dialectal adjective for "poor air" according to *[A Dictionary of North East Dialect](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Dictionary_of_North_East_Dialect/bYUGzRha3A8C?hl=en&gbpv=0)*; the author has quotations ranging from 1868 to 2001. That definition matches with the smoky atmosphere that your family used this word to describe: not the oil itself, but the smoke that accompanied it. I can't find anything that matches your definition exactly—though the *[The English Dialect Dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_English_Dialect_Dictionary_Being_the/eGghAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*'s "A suffocating smell or vapour, reek, stench; a close atmosphere; smoke" comes closer, albeit with the caveat that it's used mainly for smoke from mines—but they're similar enough in meaning that I think this is the explanation for why your family uses that word.

As for if anyone else has heard of this, a 'Mr. Cat' [over on Word Reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/stife.2152491/?hl=1) seems to have.